# Why does BIOS operate in 16-bits instead of 32/64-bits?

Tags: boot, bios, 64-bit, 32-bit, 16-bit

My teacher tells me that BIOS (or Legacy Mode) **always** boot-up my PC in 16 bits.

In other words, I can have an Intel Core i291832 with 23.9GHz, but my PC will operate in 16-bits mode if I'm using Legacy Mode. Is that true? If so, why does it happen?

*P.S: you can be very technical, I'm coursing computer science probably will understand what you say. 
P.S2: I know the differences between UEFI and Legacy Mode.*

Comment: Wikipedia: "BIOS limitations (such as 16-bit processor mode, 1 MB addressable space and PC AT hardware) had become too restrictive for the larger server platforms Itanium was targeting. The effort to address these concerns began in 1998 and was initially called Intel Boot Initiative; it was later renamed to EFI."

Comment: Wtf? Why my question was downvoted? Your reply didn't answer anything, @ChrisInEdmonton , sorry, but I really didn't get it from your explanation.

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I was just pointing out that the current standard, EFI (or UEFI) is 32-bit.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer and sorry for being rude, I thought that you don't like the question and downvoted it without any apparent reason. Sorry and thank you for the time / patience / comment <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backwards compatibility.

A modern x86 processor can run software written for the original [8088](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088) such as MS DOS without resorting to software emulation. Note that some things may not run *well*, many games for example relied on the clock speed for timing, so what used to happen in 10 seconds at 5 MHz now happens something closer to 0.02 seconds at 2.5 GHz. Good luck reacting in time.

Real mode (16 bit) behaves differently from protected mode (32 bit) and long mode (64 bit). A program written for real mode can not run in protected or long mode, it uses different instructions.

Since backwards compatibility is one of the most important qualities of x86, all x86 processors continue to start up in real mode. (Otherwise we probably would have moved to a less insane architecture by now. Remember that even Intel wanted to switch to [Itanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium).)

The BIOS and UEFI are parts of the motherboard, not the CPU. So BIOS, remaining backwards compatible to the original IBM PC, and being very simple itself, leaves the CPU in real mode as it passes control to the boot loader. UEFI, was not designed for such backwards compatibility, and thus is free to switch into protected mode before passing on control. But if you take the same x86 CPU out of a UEFI computer and place it into a BIOS computer with a compatible motherboard, it will still work, what was jumping into 32 bit protected mode before loading the boot loader is now staying in 16 bit mode before the boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS is dead, long live UEFI!

It was clear that Intel had planned to retire the BIOS [by 2020](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2017/11/intel-to-kill-off-the-last-vestiges-of-the-ancient-pc-bios-by-2020/). And, yes, the BIOS needed to be 16-bit because it was made for 16-bit hardware, the Intel 8086/8088, and it was used by 16-bit software. PC-based DOS and software for PC-DOS uses BIOS functions, which are 16-bit 8086 instructions. The 16-bit mode was later named Real Mode and is the legacy 8086-mode in which every x86 CPU is started, even though Intel intruduced a 16-bit Protected Mode with the 80286 in 1982 and a 32-bit Protected Mode with the 80386 in 1985. AMD introduced the 64-bit Long Mode (which includes a 32-bit Protected Mode) with the Opteron in 2003.

Since it was not supported to switch down from a better mode, i.e. once in Protected Mode, going back to Real Mode is [not supported (though possible)](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11954/how-to-switch-an-80286-from-protected-to-real-mode), the CPU has to be in the lowest (oldest) mode when it is switched on, otherwise it would not be 8086-compatible, and with it BIOS-compatible.

In the 1980ies and 90ies, DOS was the widest used (IBM-PC compatible) PC operating system, followed by the DOS-based Windows 9x. Since DOS is a true 16-bit operating system, it requires the Real Mode to function. Therefore an IBM-PC compatible computer had to be 16-bit-capable and had to have a BIOS.

After the millennium and with the success of Windows XP, which is based on the 32-bit Windows NT operating system, the native 16-bit Real Mode wasn't used any more, instead 16-bit software uses the Virtual 8086 Mode, a feature of the 32-bit Protected Mode. *This Virtual 8086 Mode isn't available in the Compatibility Mode (featuring an otherwise 100% compatible 32-bit Protected Mode) inside the new Long Mode of the 64-bit x86 architecture "x64".* One could argue, since the operating system doesn't need a native 16-bit mode anymore, the CPU could start in 32-bit Protected Mode... But, no, those 32-bit (and early 64-bit) PCs still featured a BIOS (16-bit real mode assembler software) and thus the CPU had to start in Real Mode. Also, this way they stayed compatible with good old DOS...

With the advent of EFI, later UEFI, on the PC, the firmware placed the system into 32-bit Protected Mode or 64-bit Long Mode. Only in a BIOS compatible mode, called "CSM" (for Compatibility Support Module), (U)EFI has to switch back to Real Mode (und with it stay DOS compatible).

The real question is: **When after 2020 the BIOS compatibility (CSM) of UEFI is finally gone, why would it still be necessary for x86 CPUs to start in Real Mode?**

Since UEFI is the new x86 standard firmware, and after 2020 presumably always in 64-Bit Long Mode, why not start the CPU is this mode once and for all?